# What's best practices I should follow to store the generic pages in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What's the best practices I should follow to store generic pages like Homepage, Help, Contact, About us, and other pages which have not specific controller or model.

Comment: One factor in your decision may be whether or not these pages have dynamic content. Help/contact/about probably don't, but homepage often does. Could the homepage be better represented as, say, an `index` of a certain model, or does it display data from many sources?

Comment: for Homepage, yeah, it represent data from many models, and I've some pages which have the same flavor, so where should I store them?, and where should I store pages which have not dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a non-restful DefaultController that has actions for each page. Since its usually static content that takes advantage of Rails' view helpers and layout functionality, I page cache them as well.